# What is the radius of a circle given two points and the center of the circle is perpendicular to one of the points?

Tags: geometry

Is there a formula for finding the center point or radius of a circle given that you know two points on the circle and one of the points is perpendicular to the center?

I know that only having two points is not enough for determining the circle, but given that the center is on the same x coordinate as one of the points, is there a way to use those two points to find the center/radius of the circle?
So you have the following data:
x0 = 0
y0 = 0
x1 = 3
y1 = 1
y2 = ?

I want to build some ramps for my rc car and am trying to figure out the optimal curve for the ramps. The two points are the corners of a  3'x1' piece of plywood. I want to cut the best curve out of the plywood for the jump, and would like to have a formula to calculate/draw the curve for other size ramps.

Here is a diagram of the problem I am trying to solve. The rectangle will basically be a piece of plywood and the curve will be cut out of it. I am trying to solve for y2.

[image: Ramp Circle]

Basically, I am going to pin a piece of string in the ground y2 feet away from my board and attach a pencil to one end in order to mark the curve that I need to cut.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should say that the two points have the same x-coordinate, not that the points "are perpendicular".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(0, 0), B(3, 1), M(0, r)$ (we place the point $A(x_0, y_0)$ on the origin)

Then the distance between A and M (d(A, M)) is r. The distance between B and M is also r, since A and B are both points on the circle.

$d(B, M)=\sqrt{(3-0)^2+(1-r)^2}=\sqrt{r^2-2r+10}=r$ (pythagorean theorem)

$r^2=r^2-2r+10$ (square both sides)

$r=5$ (solve for $r$)

Therefore, the coordinate of the middle point is 5 foot above the point $(x_0, y_0)$ and the radius is 5.

Comment: Super simple and it works. Thank you very much. I didn't even think about the distance formula. This makes me want to go back and practice the basics again.

Answer (score 2):

It would help to convert this to a question about triangles instead.  Pictured again below with a few modifications.  (I'll use degrees as it is more common for household projects, but can easily be changed into radians as needed)

[image]

As the angle pointed to by the yellow arrow is $\arctan(\frac{1}{3})\approx 18.43^\circ$, that means the red angles are $90^\circ - \arctan(\frac{1}{3})\approx 71.57^\circ$

So, we have a $71.57, 71.57, 36.86$ triangle.

By the law of sines, $\frac{A}{\sin(a)}=\frac{B}{\sin(b)}$ you have $B = (\sqrt{3^2+1^2}\frac{\sin(71.57^\circ)}{\sin(36.86^\circ)}) \approx 5.0013$

Comment: You may want to use $\approx$ signs as the radius is actually 5.

Comment: indeed.  Such is the trouble of taking only 4 sig figs on the angle measurements.

Comment: To be more precise, with your method, the answer is $$\frac{\sqrt{(y_1-y_0)^2+(x_1-x_0)^2}*\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{|y1-y0|}{|x_1-x_0|}\right)}{\sin\left(\pi-2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\left({|y1-y0|}\over{|x_1-x_0|}\right)\right)\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you (and everyone else) for your efforts. This is a nice, elegant solution and I would accept it if I could accept two answers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the diagram, we can solve the question as follows:

Because $C = (x_0,y_2)$ is equidistant from $P_0 = (x_0,y_0)$ and $P_1 = (x_1,y_1)$, $C$ must lie on the perpendicular bisector of $P_0$ and $P_1$.

The **perpendicular bisector** of two points is the line perpendicular to the line connecting them through their midpoint.

We calculate the midpoint $P$ as
$$
P = \frac{P_0 + P_1}{2} = \left(\frac{x_0 + x_1}{2},\frac{y_0 + y_1}{2} \right) = (x_p,y_p)
$$
The slope of the line connecting two points is given by the rise-over-run formula, and the perpendicular slope is its negative reciprocal.  So, we have
$$
m = - \frac{1}{\frac{y_1 - y_0}{x_1 - x_0}} = 
- \frac{x_1 - x_0}{y_1 - y_0}
$$
Finally, the equation of a line through point $P$ and slope $m$ is given by the point slope formula.  So, the perpendicular bisector is given by the equation
$$
y - y_p = m(x - x_p)
$$
$(x_0,y_2)$ lies on this line, so that
$$
y_2 - y_p = m(x_0 - x_p)
$$
Solving for $y_2$, we have
$$
y_2 = m(x_0 - x_p) + y_p
$$
all together, we have
$$
y_2 = - \frac{x_1 - x_0}{y_1 - y_0}\left(x_0 - \frac{x_0 + x_1}{2}\right) + \frac{y_0 + y_1}{2} \implies\\
y_2 = - \frac{x_1 - x_0}{y_1 - y_0}\left(\frac{x_0 - x_1}{2}\right) + \frac{y_0 + y_1}{2} \implies\\
y_2 = \frac{(x_1 - x_0)^2}{2(y_1 - y_0)} + \frac{y_0 + y_1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

So we have a circle through the origin and $(x,y)$ whose center lies in $(0,y_0)$.

By the pythagorean theorem,
$$ y_0^2 = x^2+(y-y_0)^2 $$
so $x^2+y^2=2yy_0$ gives:
$$ y_0 = \frac{x^2+y^2}{2y}.$$

Comment: This is close, but you left out a term. This should actually be x^2 + y^2 / 2y

Comment: @bj_anderson: thanks, fixed.